# How to display sql query fired by posts_where

Tags: post-meta

I have used

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', array(&$this, 'new_filter_where' ));
function edcal_new_filter_where($where = '') {
        global $wpdb;
        $where .= " AND (($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'assignto' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = '7')) ";            
        return where;
    }
```

now how to print sql query that fired by my filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and dirty way is to put `var_dump($wp_query->request)` (or whatever you've named the `WP_Query` object if you've created a new one) on the page the query runs on and after it runs.

You can also add `define('SAVEQUERIES', true);` to `wp-config.php` to save the queries for analysis. You can read the queries something like this from the Codex:

```
if (current_user_can('administrator')){
    global $wpdb;
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($wpdb->queries);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: great buddy, its working

Comment: please have a look my another question,need your help http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113865/how-to-fire-join-query-with-post-meta